# How to pass the parameters to method when click on element without html onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass data from one page to another without going to next.php whenever I press any button.

I would remove the onclick attribute,

```
<button class="submit-btn"></button>
```

to do this

```
$(".submit-btn").click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    submit(); 
});
```

but `onclick="addMore(\'auth' + authors + '\')"` and `onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv' + count + '\')"` are passing data to the function if I make it class="addMore" and class="removeDiv" how will I pass the parameters.

The snippet has all the code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- #main {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
    <div class="my-form">
      <form action="next.php" method="post">
        <button onclick="addAuthor()">Add Author</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="addAuth"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var authors = 0;

    function addAuthor() {
      authors++;
      var str = '<br/>' + '<div id="auth' + authors + '">' + '<input type="text" name="author" id="author' + authors + '" placeholder="Author Name:"/>' + '<br/>' + '<button onclick="addMore(\'auth' + authors + '\')" >Add Book</button>' + '</div>';
      $("#addAuth").append(str);
    }

    var count = 0;

    function addMore(id) {
      count++;
      var str = '<div id="bookDiv' + count + '">' + '<input class="' + id + '" type="text" name="book' + id + '" placeholder="Book Name"/>' + '<span onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv' + count + '\')" style="font-size: 20px; background-color: red; cursor:pointer; margin-left:1%;">Remove</span>' + '</div>';
      $("#" + id).append(str);
    }

    function removeDiv(id) {
      //var val = confirm("Are you sure ..?");
      //if(val){
      $("#" + id).slideUp(function() {
        $("#" + id).remove();
      });
      //}
    }

    function submit() {
      var arr = [];
      for (i = 1; i <= authors; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = $("#author" + i).val();
        obj.books = [];
        $(".auth" + i).each(function() {
          var data = $(this).val();
          obj.books.push(data);
        });
        arr.push(obj);
      }
      sendToServer(arr)
      $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }

    function sendToServer(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          arr: JSON.stringify(data)
        },
        url: "next.php",
        success: function() {

        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To prevent a button from posting back you can re5urn false on click. So either make the function return false and add return before the function call in on click or add && false after the function call in onclick. This question has been asked many times before, just search for JavaScript button prevent navigation.

Comment: In stead of preventing default action for click events, shouldn't you be using your event.preventDefault in a handler for the onsubmit event?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit

Answer (score 2):

You can use **click(dataMap, method)** version of the jQuery [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) method

```
    $("removeDiv").click({bookDiv: count}, removeDiv);
```

check out this [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/a1d84ka9/1/)

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the attrubute `type="button"` on you button tag like this:

```
<button type="button" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
```

to prevent the form is submitted, and with jQuery handles the click:

```
$('.submit-btn').on('click', function() {
    // Your code here
    ...
});
```

I hope it helps you...

Comment: `onclick="addMore(\'auth' + authors + '\')"` and `onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv' + count + '\')"` are passing data to the function if I make it class="addMore" and class="removeDiv" how will I pass the parameters.